# How to exit a memory in Assassin's Creed: Revelations?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I may be at a spot where exiting isn't possible (it's the first memory I've tried to leave). I'm doing a (spoiler alert, I guess?) Sophia memory where you have to

> get the Apple from Abbas.

I decided I wanted to run around Constantinople for a bit before I do this annoying level, but I can't find the option to leave the memory.

Am I missing something here? I can't see the option in the menu.

Alternatively, if I were to pick another memory to replay (if this is possible) would I then be thrown back into free-roam, where I want to be?

Hopefully that made sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you playing the memory for the first time? I'm not sure, but you may not be able to quit memories from the DNA menu unless it is a level replay.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure you can't quit a memory the first time through.

Comment: I think if you die or somehow fail the mission, it will ask if you want to replay. Have you tried doing it from the start menu?

Answer (score 1):

For me I just went into the menu and clicked on the option for "Abort Memory" when I was in the mission.

Answer (score 0):

When you are at the assassin's den and get that message, go to the roof of the building.  Talking to the person on the roof will let the game continue from that point.